# How to use two list in a file together?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have to read words from a file and check if they are there in a list that i have, if it is present i should replace it with another word correspondingly. example

my first list: IAS , I.A.S , IPS , WHO ...
my second list: Indian Administrative services, Indian Administrative services, Indian Police Service, World Health Organisation...

If IAS is there in the input file it should be written in to the output file as Indian Police service. For now i have used simple if and else statements to do it. But is there any other efficient way to do it? Can i use two lists and write into the file... can i keep the list of words and its corresponding abbreviations in a file seperately and process?

File with word and abbr list(abbr file):

IAS          Indian Administartive service

WHO          World Health Organisation

Now, i want to read from my input file(infile) and check if word is there in this "abbr" file, if yes then replace else write the word itself back to a file(outfile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `zip` to create a dictionary mapping the two together:

```
>>> acronyms = ["IAS", "I.A.S", "IPS", "WHO"]
>>> expansions = ["Indian Administrative services", "Indian Administrative services", 
                  "Indian Police Service", "World Health Organisation"]
>>> map_ = dict(zip(acronyms, expansions))
>>> map_
{'I.A.S': 'Indian Administrative services', 'IAS': 'Indian Administrative services', 
 'WHO': 'World Health Organisation', 'IPS': 'Indian Police Service'}
>>> map_["IAS"]
'Indian Administrative services'
```

You can then easily replace acronyms straight from this dictionary, e.g. as a very simple example:

```
for word in sentence:
    if word in map_:
        print map_[word]
    else:
        print word
```

The `word in ...` check is much faster for dictionary keys than for items in a list.

Comment: it works well... can i keep a like "word:abbr" and process, is that possible?

Comment: The word and abbr list are very long, so if i can keep word tab abbr or word:abbr it will be easier to process. can i keep like that??

Comment: @charvi it is not clear what you are asking. Please give example input and output.

Comment: I mean to say that the words are in column1 and the abbr are in column2 in a file, how do i process it?

Comment: @charvi that is a wholly different question, and there are many duplicates here. I suggest you start with [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)